# Is there a way Codeigniter Cart Library can update options?

Tags: codeigniter, cart

I am using CI Cart Library and I've tried to update the cart this way:

```
$data = 
    array(
          array(
          'rowid'   => $this->input->post('id'.$i),
           'qty'     => $this->input->post('qty'.$i),   
           'options'=>array('subproducts'=>
                                       array(
                            'subproduct_id'=>$subrows,
                         'subprod_total'=>$subprod_tot,
                         'subquantity'=>$subquant,
                                              'subproduct_price'=>$subprod_price

                            ) 
                   )                
            );
```

but to no avail because only the product quantity is updated. If anyone knows a good approach? Thanks!

Comment: I'd also like to know if there's some way to do this...and more specifically if there is a reason why it was omitted?

Answer (score 0):

since row_id in CI made by combining these values so,if you have to update the options as well the you have to override or write your own function to update the row_id.
And to form the row_id use this expression..

```
$rowid = md5($items['id'].implode('', $items['options']));
```